# How can I make an inline span tag to go to the next line without having to change its display to block?

Tags: html, css

How can I make an *inline* `span` tag to go to the next line without having to change its display to block?

I want to preserve its *inline* behaviours because the `span` tag is meant to contain a short message. However, because it is inline, its position continues from its previous element (beside its previous element). I need the span to position to the next line, that's, below its previous element rather than side by side.

Is it possible to do this without changing its display to block?

Comment: `inline-block` doesn't work. It brings it down to the next line but the behaviours are still like a block.

Comment: You cannot do it, you want an `inline` element to act like a `block` element without considere it like a `block`…

Comment: so you can try yet `display: table`

Comment: What *inline* behaviors do you want to preserve exactly?

Comment: @Matthew I actually wanted to highlight a strip of text like a label. So I simply set the background colour. A block element would essentially colour the entire background of the block. This why I wanted an inline behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:

```
span:before{
 content: '\a' ; 
 white-space: pre;  
}
```

The `\a` is from: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#strings :

*A string cannot directly contain a newline. To include a newline in a string, use an escape representing the line feed character in ISO-10646 (U+000A), such as "\A" or "\00000a". This character represents the generic notion of "newline" in CSS.*

Comment: Thanks! This is an interesting method. But what exact is the '\a'? What does it add to the content? This does the job by making the span tag to go to the next line but as I have some colour for the background of the span tag, I can see a short strip of the span element just next to its previous element.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw the span into a block element, like a paragraph element.  Or you could place an invisible horizontal rule between the span and the elements you want to be on the previous line.  Or you could throw in a line break element.